# Comparing columns from two CSV files - follow-up

Tags: python, csv

This is the second part of a question, you can find the first part here:

[Comparing columns from two CSV files](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/208144/comparing-columns-from-two-csv-files?noredirect=1#comment401973_208144)

I've made some changes to the script and here is what it looks like now:

```
import csv, sys

def get_column(columns, name):
    count = 0
    for column in columns:
        if column != name:
            count += 1
        else:
            return(count)

def set_up_file(file, variable):
    columns = next(file)
    siren_pos = get_column(columns, 'SIREN')
    nic_pos = get_column(columns, 'NIC')
    variable_pos = get_column(columns, variable)
    return(siren_pos, nic_pos, variable_pos)

def test_variable(variable):
    with open('source.csv', 'r') as source:
        source_r = csv.reader(source, delimiter=';')
        sir_s, nic_s, comp_s = set_up_file(source_r, variable)
        line_s = next(source_r)
        with open('tested.csv', 'r') as tested:
            tested_r = csv.reader(tested, delimiter=';')
            sir_t, nic_t, comp_t = set_up_file(tested_r, variable)
            size = sum(1 for line in tested_r)
            tested.seek(0, 0)
            line_t = next(tested_r)
            line_t = next(tested_r)
            correct = 0
            try:
                while True:
                    if(line_s[sir_s] == line_t[sir_t] 
                    and line_s[nic_s] == line_t[nic_t]):
                        if(line_s[comp_s] == line_t[comp_t]):
                            correct += 1
                        line_t = next(tested_r)
                        line_s = next(source_r)
                    elif(int(line_s[sir_s]) > int(line_t[sir_t])):
                        line_t = next(tested_r)
                    elif(int(line_s[sir_s]) < int(line_t[sir_t])):
                        line_s = next(source_r)
                    else:
                        if(int(line_s[nic_s]) > int(line_t[nic_t])):
                            line_t = next(tested_r)
                        else:
                            line_s = next(source_r)
            except StopIteration:
                return(correct / size * 100)

def main():
    with open('tested.csv', 'r') as file:
        file_r = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
        columns = next(file_r)
        found = test_variable('SIREN')
        for column in columns:
            print(column, '%.2f' % (test_variable(column) / found * 100))

if(__name__ == "__main__"):
    main()
```

There are no real performance issue in the new version but I feel like it could still be improved greatly.

Also, would it be possible to reduce the size of the `test_variable` function? I thought about cutting it right before the `try` statement but I'll end up passing about 7 parameters which is not really a clean solution in my opinion.

Comment: You're missing the `get_column` function. This cannot be properly reviewed until you provide all of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There is some duplication of code because you are handling two files.
- When you need some data converted to `int` it would be best to do soon as you've read it to avoid sprinkling other logic with `int()` calls.
- The two columns SIREN and NIC combined seem to form a sorting key to the file. You could simplify the `if elif...` part by performing the comparisons on `(SIREN, NIC)` tuples.

To address the above, I propose to organize the code like this:

```
def parse_file(file, variable):
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
    sir_s, nic_s, comp_s = set_up_file(reader, variable)
    for line in reader:
        key = int(line[sir_s]), int(line[nic_s])
        yield key, line[comp_s]

def test_variable(variable):
    with open('source.csv', 'r') as source, open('tested.csv', 'r') as tested:
        source_r = parse_file(source, variable)
        tested_r = parse_file(tested, variable)

        correct = 0
        try:
            line_s = next(source_r)
            line_t = next(tested_r)
            while True:
                key_s, comp_s = line_s
                key_t, comp_t = line_t
                if line_s == line_t:
                    correct += 1
                if key_s >= key_t:
                    line_t = next(tested_r)
                if key_s <= key_t:
                    line_s = next(source_r)

        except StopIteration:
            return correct
```

Note however that I've omitted the computation of `size`. This could be done by incrementing a variable after reading each line, but since lines are read at multiple places, and some may be left in the end if the other file ends first, it may be best to count the lines separately like you have done.

Comment: I would need some details on how `key_s, comp_s = line_s` works because `comp_s` is not re-used in the code after that yet it seems to manage the calculations

Comment: @Comte_Zero Well actually `comp_s` is a redundant variable, you could also use `key_s = line_s[0]`. Because `line_s == line_t` compares all three columns at once, a separate variable is not needed.

Comment: The problem had to do with my non-understanding of yield, I've done some research and it is fine now, thanks for your answer it is really helpful but how about removing `key_s, comp_s = line_s` and using `line_s[0]` instead of `key_s` in the rest of the file, wouldn't it save some memory space / performances ?

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
return(siren_pos, nic_pos, variable_pos)
```

you do not need to surround the return values in parens. They will be returned as a tuple anyway.

It seems ill-advised to iterate through the entire file just to count the number of lines. I advise incrementing `size` as you go along, so that you only have to iterate once.

You have a bunch of common code that applies to both files. I recommend writing function that does the `open()`, the `csv.reader()`, and the `set_up_file()`.

Comment: I'd prefer keeping the parens around the return value for clarity, size has to be counted outside of the loop because said loop depend on two iterator and is not consistant but what you said on duplicate code is true, that has been changed, thanks